# How cast a managed array in C++ CLI?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, command-line-interface

I'm migrating some C# code to C++ CLI, And I need cast a managed array of `ushort`

This is the C# code

```
foreach(ushort v in mo.Properties["ChassisTypes"].Value as ushort[])
```

And this is my attempt so far

```
for each(USHORT ^v in (USHORT[] ^) mo.Properties["ChassisTypes"].Value)
```

unfortunatly this is give me some errors

> 1 IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed
>
> 2 IntelliSense:expected a ')'
>
> 3 IntelliSense: expression must have class type

What is the proper way to cast this kind of arrays in C++ CLI?

Comment: I believe "as" translates to a dynamic_cast.

Comment: `ushort[]` => `array<UInt16>`

Comment: It is `safe_cast<>` for the cast, `array<unsigned short>^` for the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
for each(UInt16 v in (array<UInt16>^)(mo->Properties["ChassisTypes"]->Value))
{
}
```

For safety you can use `dynamic_cast` as @Ben said.

```
array<UInt16>^ chassisTypes = dynamic_cast<array<UInt16>^>(mo->Properties["ChassisTypes"]->Value);
if (chassisTypes != nullptr)
    for each(UInt16 v in chassisTypes)
    {
    }
```